# Sum one column in query

Tags: mysql

In my mysql query I get the columns latitude, longitutde and total. With the lat and long I do some calculating stuff which will be printed in a alias column. That works so far. The reult would look something like this:

```
Lat         long        length  total
-----------------------------------------
49.236000   11.637500   3100    0.401500
49.178900   11.731900   3100    0.553000
49.582100   10.988300   3600    0.593800
```

Now I would like to sum all values in the length column to get a value `total_length`

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, length, (ABS( latitude - 49.439810 ) + ABS( longitude - 11.439810 )) as total FROM records ORDER BY total LIMIT 20
```

Is it even possible to only sum up one column?

What I need would be something like this:

```
Lat         long        length  total
-----------------------------------------
49.236000   11.637500   3100    0.401500
49.178900   11.731900   3100    0.553000
49.582100   10.988300   3600    0.593800
----------------------------------------
                        9800
```

There will be a given value like `20000`. if the total_length is smaller then `20000` the `LIMIT` should be add up 10 and calculate the total_length again. Do is as often until the total_length is 20000 or more.

The request to the SQL DB will be from a node.js backend.

Comment: It is not very clear what the Output should be, can you get the expected result for the example?

Comment: How are you "consuming" the query result? (PHP? C#?, Java? ...)  it's probably easier and more efficient to do it in the product than to do it in MySQL particularly as you are using limit which indicates pagination.

Comment: Yes, but it will convey only one row, or multiple rows with the same value repeated.

Comment: @Jens I added the expected result

Comment: @Used_By_Already the request will be from a node.js backend so it will be JavaScript

Comment: Is there a reason why SUM(expr) can't be used in a separate query, or am I missing something.

Comment: Releated, and possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450660/select-rows-until-a-total-amount-is-met-in-a-column-mysql

Comment: FWIW, I'd handle this aspect of the problem in application code (e.g. JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

I would split the problem in half and compute the sum with a different query.

```
SELECT SUM(length) 
FROM records
```

To get the exact result you are asking for, you would probably have to do some magic trick like this:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, length, (ABS( latitude - 49.439810 ) + ABS( longitude - 11.439810 )) as total 
FROM records ORDER BY total LIMIT 20
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM(length), NULL 
FROM records
LIMIT 20
```

It works, but having a "tailored" row isn't what I would call a clean approach.

Comment: The problem here is `SUM(length)...FROM records`  will sum up all entrys in the table records, but that are a lot. I just want to sum up the values which are in the result of the first query

Comment: Just add the `LIMIT` clause

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rollup trick here if you really need a single query:

```
SELECT
    latitude,
    longitude,
    ABS(latitude - 49.439810) + ABS(longitude - 11.439810) AS total,
    SUM(length)
FROM records
GROUP BY
    latitude,
    longitude,
    ABS(latitude - 49.439810) + ABS(longitude - 11.439810)
WITH ROLLUP 
HAVING
    (longitude IS NOT NULL AND total IS NOT NULL) OR latitude IS NULL;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Read it and keep it in your back pocket at all times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837262/mysql-only-get-overall-rollup

Comment: I use phpmyadmin to admin my database. But it looks like it don't know the keys `WITH` and `ROLLUP`

Comment: @WeSt The above query should certainly run directly from MySQL Workbench.  I can't vouch for other things.

Comment: `total` is not a column of the table. `total` is a alias for the calculated value

Comment: @WeSt I updated my query, but this doesn't change the basic answer I gave.