# How to skip to be rollup a specific column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rollup

I have a query and I have used `with rollup` for making a report. Now I need to skip a column to be rollup, I don't need the extra summary row like `part` from the following query

```
SELECT coalesce(K.ShipName,'Grand Total')ShipName, K.AREA_ID, coalesce(K.PostingName,'Ship Total')PostingName, coalesce(K.Branch,'Unit Total')Branch, coalesce(K.RANK_NAME,'Branch Total')RANK_NAME , K.Part, ifnull(sum(K.Borne),0)Borne, ifnull(sum(K.sanction),0)sanction, sum(K.TotalIn)TotalIn, sum(K.TotalOut)TotalOut
FROM (
      SELECT ShipName, AREA_ID, PostingName,Branch, RANK_NAME, ifnull(Part,'') Part, Borne, sanction, TotalIn, TotalOut
      FROM (
            SELECT sh.NAME ShipName,sh.AREA_ID, pu.NAME PostingName, b.BRANCH_NAME Branch, r.RANK_NAME , p.Name Part, COUNT(SAILORID)Borne,
            (SELECT SUM(us.SanctionNo)sanction FROM unitwisesanction us WHERE us.RankID = s.RANKID AND us.PostingUnitID = s.POSTINGUNITID
            AND us.PartIIID = s.FIRSTPARTID GROUP BY us.PostingUnitID,us.RankID,us.PartIIID) sanction,

            (SELECT COUNT(t.TransferID)TotalOut FROM transfer t LEFT JOIN sailor ts ON t.SailorID = ts.SAILORID WHERE ts.RANKID = s.RANKID
            AND ts.FIRSTPARTID = s.FIRSTPARTID AND t.PostingUnitID = s.POSTINGUNITID )TotalIn,

            (SELECT COUNT(t.TransferID)TotalOut FROM transfer t LEFT JOIN sailor ts ON t.SailorID = ts.SAILORID WHERE ts.RANKID = s.RANKID
            AND ts.FIRSTPARTID = s.FIRSTPARTID AND ts.POSTINGUNITID = s.POSTINGUNITID )TotalOut

            FROM sailor s
            LEFT JOIN bn_branch b ON s.BRANCHID = b.BRANCH_ID
            LEFT JOIN bn_rank r ON s.RANKID = r.RANK_ID
            LEFT JOIN partii p ON s.FIRSTPARTID = p.PartIIID
            LEFT JOIN bn_daogroup a ON b.DAO_GROUPID = a.GROUP_ID
            LEFT JOIN bn_ship_establishment sh ON s.SHIPESTABLISHMENTID = sh.SHIP_ESTABLISHMENTID
            LEFT JOIN bn_posting_unit pu ON s.POSTINGUNITID = pu.POSTING_UNITID
            WHERE SAILORSTATUS = 1 AND s.ZONEID IN (1) AND s.SHIPESTABLISHMENTID IN (53,125) AND a.GROUP_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,7)
            GROUP BY s.POSTINGUNITID, RANKID, FIRSTPARTID) a
  ) K
GROUP BY ShipName, PostingName, Branch, RANK_NAME, Part WITH ROLLUP
HAVING Part IS NOT NULL OR RANK_NAME IS NULL
```

Exactly I don't need the color marked records in the following screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL only get overall ROLLUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837262/mysql-only-get-overall-rollup)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using the following query

```
SELECT coalesce(K.ShipName,'Area Total')ShipName, K.AREA_ID, coalesce(K.PostingName,'Ship Total')PostingName, coalesce(K.Branch,'Unit Total')Branch, coalesce(K.RANK_NAME,'Branch Total')RANK_NAME , K.Part, sum(K.Borne)Borne, sum(K.sanction)sanction, sum(K.TotalIn)TotalIn, sum(K.TotalOut)TotalOut
FROM (
      SELECT ShipName, AREA_ID, PostingName,Branch, RANK_NAME, ifnull(Part,'') Part, Borne, sanction, TotalIn, TotalOut
      FROM (
            SELECT sh.NAME ShipName,sh.AREA_ID, pu.NAME PostingName, b.BRANCH_NAME Branch, r.RANK_NAME , p.Name Part, COUNT(SAILORID)Borne,
            (SELECT SUM(us.SanctionNo)sanction FROM unitwisesanction us WHERE us.RankID = s.RANKID AND us.PostingUnitID = s.POSTINGUNITID
            AND us.PartIIID = s.FIRSTPARTID GROUP BY us.PostingUnitID,us.RankID,us.PartIIID) sanction,

            (SELECT COUNT(t.TransferID)TotalOut FROM transfer t LEFT JOIN sailor ts ON t.SailorID = ts.SAILORID WHERE ts.RANKID = s.RANKID
            AND ts.FIRSTPARTID = s.FIRSTPARTID AND t.PostingUnitID = s.POSTINGUNITID )TotalIn,

            (SELECT COUNT(t.TransferID)TotalOut FROM transfer t LEFT JOIN sailor ts ON t.SailorID = ts.SAILORID WHERE ts.RANKID = s.RANKID
            AND ts.FIRSTPARTID = s.FIRSTPARTID AND ts.POSTINGUNITID = s.POSTINGUNITID )TotalOut

            FROM sailor s
            LEFT JOIN bn_branch b ON s.BRANCHID = b.BRANCH_ID
            LEFT JOIN bn_rank r ON s.RANKID = r.RANK_ID
            LEFT JOIN partii p ON s.FIRSTPARTID = p.PartIIID
            LEFT JOIN bn_daogroup a ON b.DAO_GROUPID = a.GROUP_ID
            LEFT JOIN bn_ship_establishment sh ON s.SHIPESTABLISHMENTID = sh.SHIP_ESTABLISHMENTID
            LEFT JOIN bn_posting_unit pu ON s.POSTINGUNITID = pu.POSTING_UNITID
            WHERE SAILORSTATUS = 1 AND s.ZONEID IN (1) AND s.SHIPESTABLISHMENTID IN (53,125) AND a.GROUP_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,7)
            GROUP BY s.POSTINGUNITID, RANKID, FIRSTPARTID) a
  ) K
GROUP BY ShipName, PostingName, Branch, RANK_NAME, Part WITH ROLLUP
HAVING Part IS NOT NULL OR RANK_NAME IS NULL
```

Comment: Looks like you're still rolling up `Part` and just skipping records where it was rolled up to null.  You could do the same thing with a subquery and `where` clause - calling `having` for those values doesn't actually stop the rollup.