# How can I filter out subtotals when using WITH ROLLUP in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-null

I'm trying to use GROUP ... WITH ROLLUP to get a series of totals for multiple grouped values, but without subtotals. So in my contrived example, I have a table `fruits` which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY fruit;
+----+----------+------+-------+
| id | fruit    | size | price |
+----+----------+------+-------+
|  1 | apple    |    3 |  4.99 |
|  2 | apple    |    4 |  5.99 |
|  3 | apple    |    6 |  2.99 |
|  8 | apple    |    3 |  3.00 |
|  9 | apple    |    4 |  6.50 |
|  4 | banana   |    2 |  3.50 |
|  5 | banana   |    3 |  2.10 |
|  6 | banana   |    1 |  8.99 |
|  7 | banana   |    7 |  6.99 |
| 10 | banana   |    3 |  3.50 |
| 14 | banana   |    7 |  8.00 |
| 11 | cucumber |    1 |  1.50 |
| 12 | cucumber |    1 |  2.30 |
| 13 | cucumber |    2 |  3.30 |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

Let's say I want to group the fruits table by both `fruit` and `size`, and display the average price at the bottom. I can use GROUP WITH ROLLUP to achieve this:

```
SELECT fruit, size, AVG(price) FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit, size WITH ROLLUP;
+----------+------+------------+
| fruit    | size | AVG(price) |
+----------+------+------------+
| apple    |    3 |   3.995000 |
| apple    |    4 |   6.245000 |
| apple    |    6 |   2.990000 |
| apple    | NULL |   4.694000 |
| banana   |    1 |   8.990000 |
| banana   |    2 |   3.500000 |
| banana   |    3 |   2.800000 |
| banana   |    7 |   7.495000 |
| banana   | NULL |   5.513333 |
| cucumber |    1 |   1.900000 |
| cucumber |    2 |   3.300000 |
| cucumber | NULL |   2.366667 |
| NULL     | NULL |   4.546429 |
+----------+------+------------+
```

But I don't want all of those subtotal rows... I just want the last row, where both `fruit` and `size` show NULL. In other words, this:

```
+----------+------+------------+
| fruit    | size | AVG(price) |
+----------+------+------------+
| apple    |    3 |   3.995000 |
| apple    |    4 |   6.245000 |
| apple    |    6 |   2.990000 |
| banana   |    1 |   8.990000 |
| banana   |    2 |   3.500000 |
| banana   |    3 |   2.800000 |
| banana   |    7 |   7.495000 |
| cucumber |    1 |   1.900000 |
| cucumber |    2 |   3.300000 |
| NULL     | NULL |   4.546429 |
+----------+------+------------+
```

I don't have access to MySQL 8.0 so I cannot use the `GROUPING()` function [described in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to determine whether a value in a row represents a subtotal or a grand total. So I figure I have to filter out `NULL` values.

I tried to adapt [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388258/1907765) like so:

```
SELECT fruit, size, AVG(price) FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit, size WITH ROLLUP HAVING size IS NOT NULL or fruit IS NULL;
+----------+------+------------+
| fruit    | size | AVG(price) |
+----------+------+------------+
| apple    |    3 |   3.995000 |
| apple    |    4 |   6.245000 |
| apple    |    6 |   2.990000 |
| banana   |    1 |   8.990000 |
| banana   |    2 |   3.500000 |
| banana   |    3 |   2.800000 |
| banana   |    7 |   7.495000 |
| cucumber |    1 |   1.900000 |
| cucumber |    2 |   3.300000 |
+----------+------+------------+
```

As you can see though, this doesn't generate the result I want - it just chops off the grand total entirely. I know that I want to get only rows where size is non-null and fruit is either null or not null, but the various ways I've tried to test for NULL haven't worked as I expected:

```
SELECT fruit, size, AVG(price), fruit IS NULL, fruit IS NOT NULL, ISNULL(fruit), fruit = "" FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit, size WITH ROLLUP;
+----------+------+------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| fruit    | size | AVG(price) | fruit IS NULL | fruit IS NOT NULL | ISNULL(fruit) | fruit = "" |
+----------+------+------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| apple    |    3 |   3.995000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| apple    |    4 |   6.245000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| apple    |    6 |   2.990000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| apple    | NULL |   4.694000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| banana   |    1 |   8.990000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| banana   |    2 |   3.500000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| banana   |    3 |   2.800000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| banana   |    7 |   7.495000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| banana   | NULL |   5.513333 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| cucumber |    1 |   1.900000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| cucumber |    2 |   3.300000 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| cucumber | NULL |   2.366667 |             0 |                 1 |             0 |          0 |
| NULL     | NULL |   4.546429 |             0 |                 0 |             0 |       NULL |
+----------+------+------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
```

None of these results really make sense. I would assume that `fruit is NULL` or `ISNULL(fruit)` would return 1 when the value for fruit is actually NULL. But they don't. So I wondered if this was something to do with the difference between an empty string and null ... but I don't understand why, when I test for `fruit = ""`, it returns NULL when the fruit is NULL.

What condition am I supposed to use to test for NULL, so that I can exclude the results I want from my table?

Comment: *I would assume that fruit is NULL or ISNULL(fruit) would return 1 when the value for fruit is actually NULL* yes they do return 1.

Comment: @forpas In the example I've shown both of those fields do not show 1 at all, even when there is a `NULL` value in the `fruit` column. So is that `NULL` value not actually `NULL`?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use your aggregation query as a subquery and filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT fruit, size, AVG(price) avg_price
  FROM fruits 
  GROUP BY fruit, size 
  WITH ROLLUP
) t
WHERE (fruit IS NOT NULL AND size IS NOT NULL)
   OR (fruit IS NULL AND size IS NULL)
```

You could also do it without a subquery, with a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT fruit, size, AVG(price) avg_price
FROM fruits 
GROUP BY fruit, size 
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING (fruit IS NOT NULL AND size IS NOT NULL)
    OR (fruit IS NULL AND size IS NULL)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=de8cf8e945ea6d23b2825429c7edefee).

Comment: Thank you, this looks great! Is there no way to do it without a subquery? I'm worried about the potential performance impact in my real use case, as my data might be a lot larger.

Comment: Thank you. It's weird though, I run the exact same query you've got in my MySQL editor and it doesn't show the last row - i.e. it's missing the total. My version is 5.7.18.

Comment: @Lou the demo I provide in my answer works for MySql 5.5.62+ Try another tool.

Answer (score 1):

No subquery is needed.  You can use a `having` clause:

```
select fruit, size, avg(price)
from fruits
group by fruit, size with rollup
having fruit is not null and size is not null or
       fruit is null and size is null;
```

There are other ways of expressing the `having`, such as:

```
having (fruit is not null) = (size is not null)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47f10e8609e1d99622ff9e81c8643573) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That's weird - like @forpas' answer, when I run your query in my MySQL environment it does not show the last row. I'm running 5.7.18 - but I've tried changing the SQLfiddle to 5.7 and it gives the correct result on there. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong locally.

Comment: @Lou . . . That is really strange.  The second version works in 5.7:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=47f10e8609e1d99622ff9e81c8643573.